# Weird behaviour using mipmapping from glsl

Tags: glsl, vulkan

I am trying to use mipmapping with vulkan. I do understand that I should use vkCmdBlit between each layer for each image, but before doing that, I just wanted to know how to change the layer in GLSL.

Here is what I did.
First I load and draw a texture (using layer 0) and there was no problem. The "rendered image" is the texture I load, so it is good.

Second, I use this shader (so I wanted to use the second layer (number 1)) but the "rendered image" does not change :

```
#version 450

layout(set = 0, binding = 0) uniform sampler2D tex;

in vec2 texCoords;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor;

void main() {
    outColor = textureLod(tex, texCoords, 1);
}
```

According to me, the rendered image should be changed, but not at all, it is always the same image, even if I increase the "1" (the number of the layer).

Third instead changing anything in the glsl code, I change the layer number into the ImageSubresourceRange to create the imageView, and the "rendered image" changed, so it seems normal to me and when I will use vkCmdBlit, I must see the original image in lower resolution.

The real problem is, when I try to use a mipmapping (through mipmapping) in GLSL, it does not affect at all the rendered image, but in C++ it does (and that seems fair).

here is (all) my source code
https://github.com/qnope/Vulkan-Example/tree/master/Mipmap

Comment: "*According to me, the rendered image should be changed, but not at all, it is always the same image, even if I increase the "1" (the number of the layer).*" Why? You're fetching from a texture. Why would where you're fetching from have any impact on what you're writing to? Do you usually expect the parameters you pass to a function call to affect which variable or memory location the function's return value gets stored in?

Comment: Since I did not use vkCmdBlit yet, the content of memory that I read should be undefined ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by your default sampler creation info (https://github.com/qnope/Vulkan-Example/blob/master/Mipmap/VkTools/System/sampler.cpp#L28) you always set the maxLod member of your samplers to zero, so your lod is always clamped between 0.0 and 0.0 (minLod/maxLod). This would fit the behaviour you described.

So try setting the maxLod member of your sampler creation info to the actual number of mip maps in your texture and changing the lod level in the shader shoudl work fine.

Comment: Thanks ! It worked
But I do not yet understand why these values should be float ^^.
I put one high value for maxLod for this sampler, in this case, I could reuse it for several textures :p

Comment: If you want to know why the min and max lod are float, check out the level-of-detail section from the specs (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/xhtml/vkspec.html#textures-level-of-detail-operation).
And using one sampler with "just a high value for maxLod" is not a good idea due to several reasons e.g. if you sample without an explicit lod.

Comment: So okay, I'd go like you
One tuple of Image/ImageView/Sampler :)

Comment: @SaschaWillems I think a single high value for maxLod would work OK because according to the "Image Level(s) Selection" section of the spec the chosen mip(s) are clamped to q which is levelCount - 1 as taken from the subresourceRange of the image view

Comment: @SaschaWillems I don't understand why using a high value for maxLod is a bad idea. Does it have any performance implications ? In my case, I am working on an abstraction layer over Vulkan and OpenGL (possibly DirectX in the future) and it would be nice if I did not have to expose yet another parameter in my abstraction layer's API, but instead set maxLod to e.g. FLT_MAX for every sampler that is created.